# ReactNative RefreshControll - Spinner freezes when I navigate to another Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

**Description**

Hello, I'm having a problem with my RefreshControl when I'm navigating to another Screen in my App. When I make the pull to trigger the refresh the spinner is spinning normally but then when I navigate to another Screen and going back to the Screen where I triggered the refresh the Spinner freezes. Does anyone can help me and maybe have a solution for this problem?

I'm having just this issue all other is working fine with the RefreshControll

iOS: Spinner freezes
Android: Spinner disappears

**Version**

0.64.3

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Steps to reproduce
2. Pull down the FlatList
3. Navigate to another screen thought the Tabs Stack Navigator or with
   useNavigation().navigate()
   4  Getting back to the screen where the refresh is Triggered
4. The spinner of the RefreshControl freezes (iOS) or disappears (Andorid)

iOS:

https://files.fm/f/u89vdn3p8

Andorid:

https://files.fm/f/j6s8kbyqj

Comment: Have you found any fix?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: I'm stopping loader when user leaves the screen, so we avoided the loader UI freeze